# I sent my Bitcoin from Coinbase Wallet back to my coinbase wallet address. I basically sent it to myself but can't get access to it

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com, cash-app

I tried sending my Bitcoin from my coinbase wallet address to my cash app Bitcoin account but accidentally copied and pasted the Coinbase Wallet address instead of the cash app Bitcoin account. So basically I sent back to myself. It's confirmed but I don't have access to the funds. I see it but can't touch it. Coinbase Wallet support has led me on for a month and won't help. Can someone please help me. That's my wedding money.

Comment: This is a community forum, we have no sway over any companies interactions with you. It sounds like you’ve done something that has potentially lost your money administratively (sending “back” to an address isn’t something that happens in bitcoin), but nobody else can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Sending Bitcoin back to your own address should just give you an error, nothing would be lost on-chain.  This is probably an internal Conbase error they should have coded their system to recognize and reject.

Conbase Support Level 1 is extremely understaffed, undertrained, likely is overloaded with requests, and probably does not understand the issue in the first place.  You need to escalate to a Level 2 or 3 rep who can dig into the Conbase system and get your Bitcoins back.  Level 1 support likely cannot assist you.  Not because they are incompetent, but because Coinbase is not properly equipping them to do their job, with low staffing levels and poor training

I highly doubt your transaction was actually posted to the Blockchain, meaning you never lost any funds. This is an internal issue to Conbase

I recommend taking the issue to social media if you are getting clogged up at Tier 1 support, a social media manager may see the bad publicity and be able to get you connected with a higher level support rep.  Try talking to some of the Coinbase competition, such as eToro, iTrustCapital, RocketCoin, or MyDigitalMoney.  They can not do anything to recover your funds, but they may (may!) smell some cheap PR, and reimburse you with some of their own Bitcoins, to prove how unreliable Conbase is, and how reliable they are, if you can provide proof that you have tried and failed for months to get anywhere with Conbase.  If I was them, that is what I would do!  Just a suggestion

Also, ALWAYS keep coins in your own hardware wallet, never leave them sitting in an exchange, for this exact reason!